# Counting Number of attemps left using ajax

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp

My problem is as follow : 
I am making an ajax call to a jsp and its success part is like this :

```
success: function(msg){
                alert(msg);
                    if(msg.indexOf("false")>=0)
                    {
                        var counter=$('#attemptsleft').value+1;
                        $('#attemptsleft').val(counter);
                        var left=3-counter;
                        if(left>=0)
                        alert("You have "+left+" attemps left");
                        else
                            alert("You have no attempts left");
                    }
                    else{
                        alert("success");
                    }

            }
```

Actually what i want to do is that to provide number of attempts to the user and if he exceeds those then tell that their are no more attempts left.

In html am doing this :

```
<input type="hidden" id="attemptsleft" value="0"></input>
```

Where am doing wrong.As am not getting results which were expected.

Comment: If you use alert than page will refresh..remove `alert` code, and check again.

Comment: @TBM Remove alert from where ?

Comment: after `if(left>=0)` condition, there you use `alert`.

Comment: @TBM I need to tell the user that he has these many attempts left.How can i do it without alert msg

Answer (score 0):

You aren't checking the condition when deciding whether to give success.

As an aside, you can just store the attempts value in a javascript variable, instead of using an input.

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen? What exactly is currently happening instead?

Comment: I have a jsp that is making an ajax call and other jsp that is being called.The called jsp just send a msg back of true or false.If that is false  I want that the user should be having three chances And after those three chances are over then redirect back him to main page of web application.Otherwise the value is true then move him to next page.

Comment: So where is the problem exactly? Try breaking it down and figuring out exactly which part isn't working. Is the problem in counting the number of failures, or redirecting, or something else? It looks like you should be checking the if(left>0) condition at the beginning of the success function, but it's hard to tell without more context.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this one :

success: function(msg){
            alert(msg);
                if(msg.indexOf("false")>=0)
                {
                    var counter=parseInt($('#attemptsleft').value)+1;
                    $('#attemptsleft').val(counter);
                    var left=3-counter;
                    if(left>=0)
                    alert("You have "+left+" attemps left");
                    else
                        alert("You have no attempts left");
                }
                else{
                    alert("success");
                }

        }

 I just added a parseInt() while increment the attempts left value.
```